# Make an <a> tag in a footer stick to the left and the other to the right

Tags: html, css

I have two  tags one links to the ***previous*** page and the other one to the ***next***, and I have put both of them in the footer. In CSS, I can't get each tag to stick to its side of the footer without the other joining it.

The first thing I tried is setting "right" to 0 for "next" and "left" for "previous" but it didn't work. I tried "text-align" but that only put them in the center.

```
--!> HTML <--
<footer>
<a class="prev" onclick="location.href='#'">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="location.href='#'">&#10095;</a>
</footer>

/* CSS */


  /* Next and previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
  
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

/* Footer */

 footer {
    background: rgba(0,136,169,1);
    color: #090e5e;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) like below to make sure `<a>` tag in footer stick to the `left` and the `other` to the right

Using `flex` is best way in modern `browsers` since its very **responsive** as well.

```
footer {
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  color: #090e5e;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Ideally i would rec-emend wrapping your `<a>` in a `div` so that styles are not applying to the whole footer but only the that  `div`

```
<footer>
  <div class="arrow_buttons">
    <a class="prev" onclick="location.href='#'">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="location.href='#'">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Using `CSS` on that `div` - like this below:

```
.arrow_buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

**Live Working Demo:**

```css
/* Next and previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: white;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  color: #090e5e;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <a class="prev" onclick="location.href='#'">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="location.href='#'">&#10095;</a>
</footer>
```